# How to "map" JSON values from a second Object level with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, external

How can i parse second level objects from a json file?
I'm new to d3.js and already created some simple barcharts out of  a single json file. 
In my "basic" learn files there were only one Item level of my Json objects so it was really understandale how i can get the values.
Now it is an external JSON file, located in the same folder.
My json file has different levels of objects. 
Heres an example of my json file ( just a simple cut ):

```
[
    {
        "Value 1": "String",
        "Value 2": 2500,
        "Value 3": [
            {
                "Value 3.1": "A",
                "Value 3.2": 100
            },
            {
                "Value 3.3": "B",
                "Value 3.4": 200
            },
        ]
    },
```

How can i get for example Value 2 for my Barchart in my Javascript code or how can i get value 3.2 / 3.4 for my axis?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

## Here is one option:

```js
let item = {a: {b: 1, c: 2}, d: {e: 3, f: 4}}; // example object

onItem = (item) => {
    // do the thing here
}

item.map((subItem) => {
    subItem.map((subItem2) => {
        onItem(subItem2);
    }
})
```